# Strange values/behavior of $_

Tags: perl

Output should be `aaabbbcccdddeee`, not `aaa555234dddeee`

```
perl -wle'
    map { for (my $i =2; $i <5; $i++) { push @a, $_ } } "a".."e";
    print @a
'
aaa555234dddeee
```

expected behavior only when referencing/dereferencing `$_` variable,

```
perl -wle'
    map { for (my $i =2; $i <5; $i++) { push @a, ${\$_} } } "a".."e";
    print @a
'
aaabbbcccdddeee
```

Is this a documented bug (or feature)?

Comment: This would be duplicate if original wasn't deleted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113295/is-this-the-weird-thing-youve-ever-seen

Comment: LOL! That deleted post was up for seconds. How did you find it? I posted it after the bug was found and fixed. I just wanted to share, but didn't feel it was appropriate.

Comment: Some things are hard to escape when you work for three letter agency. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me like this is an instance of a bug reported just last month (but that has been around for 12 years): https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=123285

It is fixed but I don't believe in any released version yet.